# Calling sencha controller function from android activity

Tags: android, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, android-webview, sencha-touch-2.1

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction();");
```

is not working for me.

Is there any other way to call a Sencha function written inside `MyController.js` from an Android activity?

I am not using PhoneGap - instead, I'm running Sencha app directly from a web view.

Is there a way to call sencha controller functions directly from android activity?
Something like this:

```
this.getApplication().getController('ControllerName').doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is JavaScript enabled for your `WebView`?

Try 
`WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings(); webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: Yes, enabled via webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Though i enabled javascript for webview, i'm not able to call a function written inside some sencha controller. Could anyone help me on this.